# Block nodes in torrc hidden service

Tags: configuration, onion-services, exit-relays

I used this torr config https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=331077.0

```
ClientOnly 1

EnforceDistinctSubnets 0

UseEntryGuards 1

NumEntryGuards 8

GeoIPExcludeUnknown 1

EntryNodes AutonomyCube,AccessNow000,AccessNow001,AccessNow002,AccessNow003,AccessNow004,AccessNow005,AccessNow006,AccessNow007,AccessNow008,AccessNow009,AccessNow010,AccessNow011,AccessNow012,AccessNow013,AccessNow014,AccessNow015,AccessNow016,AccessNow017,AccessNow018,AccessNow019,DigiGesTor1e1,DigiGesTor1e2,DigiGesTor1e3,DigiGesTor1e4,DigiGesTor2e1,DigiGesTor2e2,DigiGesTor2e3,DigiGesTor2e4,orion,orilla,destiny,chulak,aurora,assk,alf,sofia,politkovskaja,lumumba,HaveHeart,hessel0,hessel1,hessel2,edwardsnowden0,edwardsnowden1,edwardsnowden2,ekumen,marcuse1,marcuse2,marylou1,marylou2,chaoscomputerclub27,chaoscomputerclub28,chaoscomputerclub29,chaoscomputerclub30,chaoscomputerclub31,chaoscomputerclub32,chaoscomputerclub33,chaoscomputerclub34,atticus,blanqui,thoreau,enjolras,luxemburg,bakunin,bakunin2,bakunin3,bakunin4,jaures,jaures2,jaures3,jaures4,DFRI0,DFRI1,DFRI3,DFRI4,DFRI5,DFRI6,DFRI7,hviv100,hviv104,hviv105,wagtail,toreffiorg,startor0fr,startor0de,startor0nl,startor0lv,startor0se,apx1,apx2,apx3,torrelay1ph3xat,torrelay2ph3xat,symphony,vikingolaf,vikinguthar,vikinghelga,vikingbjorn,tor1multisec,tor2multisec,tor3multisec,tor4multisec,tor5multisec,CalyxInstitute07,SIGAINT1,SIGAINT2,SIGAINT3,SIGAINT4,saveyourprivacyex1,saveyourprivacyexit

ExcludeNodes Unnamed,default,kasperskytor04,37.221.171.234,tylerlockedotorg,198.58.115.210,kebab,193.142.30.66,RedOctober1917,dannenberg,193.23.244.244,dizum,194.109.206.212,Faravahar,154.35.175.225,gabelmoo,131.188.40.189,longclaw,199.254.238.52,maatuska,171.25.193.9,moria1,128.31.0.34,tor26,86.59.21.38,Tonga,82.94.251.203,{ae},{af},{ao},{az},{bh},{bi},{bn},{by},{cd},{cf},{cg},{cm},{cn},{co},{cu},{dj},{dz},{eg},{er},{et},{ga},{gm},{gq},{gt},{hn},{id},{iq},{ir},{jo},{kh},{kp},{kz},{la},{lk},{ly},{ma},{mk},{ml},{mm},{mr},{mx},{my},{ng},{om},{ph},{pk},{ps},{qa},{ru},{rw},{sa},{sd},{sg},{so},{sy},{sz},{td},{th},{tj},{tm},{tr},{ua},{ug},{uz},{ve},{vn},{ye},{zw},{ai},{aq},{as},{au},{bm},{ca},{cc},{ck},{cx},{cy},{fk},{gb},{gg},{gi},{gl},{gs},{gu},{hm},{ie},{im},{io},{je},{ky},{mp},{ms},{nf},{nu},{nz},{pn},{pr},{sh},{tc},{tk},{us},{vg},{vi}

ExcludeExitNodes {ag},{al},{am},{ar},{ba},{bb},{bd},{bf},{bg},{bj},{bo},{br},{bt},{bw},{bz},{ci},{dm},{do},{ec},{fj},{gd},{ge},{gh},{gn},{gr},{gw},{gy},{hk},{hr},{ht},{hu},{il},{in},{it},{jm},{jp},{ke},{kg},{ki},{km},{kn},{kr},{kw},{lb},{lc},{lr},{ls},{md},{me},{mg},{mn},{mo},{mu},{mv},{mw},{mz},{na},{ne},{ni},{np},{nr},{pa},{pe},{pg},{py},{sb},{sc},{sl},{sn},{tg},{tl},{tn},{to},{tt},{tw},{tv},{tz},{va},{vc},{ws},{yt},{za},{zm}

ExitNodes AutonomyCube,85.16.128.242,85.16.128.243,85.16.128.244,85.16.128.245,AccessNow000,AccessNow001,176.10.99.200,AccessNow002,AccessNow003,176.10.99.201,AccessNow004,AccessNow005,176.10.99.202,AccessNow006,AccessNow007,176.10.99.203,AccessNow008,AccessNow009,176.10.99.204,AccessNow010,AccessNow011,176.10.99.205,AccessNow012,AccessNow013,176.10.99.206,AccessNow014,AccessNow015,176.10.99.207,AccessNow016,AccessNow017,176.10.99.208,AccessNow018,AccessNow019,176.10.99.209,DigiGesTor1e1,DigiGesTor1e2,176.10.104.240,DigiGesTor1e3,DigiGesTor1e4,176.10.104.241,DigiGesTor2e1,DigiGesTor2e2,176.10.104.243,DigiGesTor2e3,DigiGesTor2e4,176.10.104.244,orion,94.242.246.24,orilla,94.242.252.41,destiny,94.242.246.23,chulak,176.126.252.11,aurora,176.126.252.12,assk,62.102.148.67,alf,77.247.181.166,sofia,77.247.181.162,politkovskaja,77.247.181.165,lumumba,77.247.181.163,HaveHeart,77.247.181.164,hessel0,109.163.234.2,hessel1,109.163.234.4,hessel2,109.163.234.5,edwardsnowden0,109.163.234.7,edwardsnowden1,109.163.234.8,edwardsnowden2,109.163.234.9,ekumen,95.142.161.63,marcuse1,178.20.55.16,marcuse2,178.20.55.18,marylou1,marylou2,89.234.157.254,chaoscomputerclub27,77.244.254.227,chaoscomputerclub28,77.244.254.228,chaoscomputerclub29,77.244.254.229,chaoscomputerclub30,77.244.254.230,chaoscomputerclub31,217.115.10.131,chaoscomputerclub32,217.115.10.132,chaoscomputerclub33,217.115.10.133,chaoscomputerclub34,217.115.10.134,atticus,46.239.117.180,blanqui,thoreau,46.165.221.166,enjolras,81.89.96.88,luxemburg,81.89.96.89,bakunin,178.16.208.57,bakunin2,178.16.208.59,bakunin3,178.16.208.61,bakunin4,178.16.208.55,jaures,178.16.208.56,jaures2,178.16.208.58,jaures3,178.16.208.60,jaures4,178.16.208.62,DFRI0,171.25.193.20,DFRI1,171.25.193.77,DFRI3,171.25.193.235,DFRI4,171.25.193.78,DFRI5,171.25.193.25,DFRI6,171.25.193.132,DFRI7,171.25.193.131,hviv100,194.104.0.100,hviv104,192.42.116.16,hviv105,79.98.107.90,wagtail,77.109.139.87,startor0se,95.215.45.187,startor0lv,185.61.149.43,apx1,176.9.25.72,apx2,85.10.210.199,apx3,5.9.36.66,toreffiorg,212.16.104.33,saveyourprivacyex1,185.100.86.100,saveyourprivacyexit,185.100.84.82,vikingolaf,193.107.85.61,vikinguthar,193.107.85.62,vikinghelga,193.107.85.56,vikingbjorn,193.107.85.57,tor1multisec,193.90.12.86,tor2multisec,193.90.12.87,tor3multisec,193.90.12.88,tor4multisec,193.90.12.89,tor5multisec,193.90.12.90,CalyxInstitute07,82.94.251.227

LongLivedPorts 21, 22, 80, 443, 706, 1863, 5050, 5190, 5222, 5223, 6523, 6667, 6697, 8300, 9001, 9030
```

But I still get US and sometimes Canadian Exit nodes I added `{ca} {uS}` to `excludenodes` but still happens any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `StrictNodes 1` directive in your `torrc`

Take a look at the [manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en), it says explicitly :

> StrictNodes 0|1
>
> If StrictNodes is set to 1, Tor will treat the ExcludeNodes option as a requirement to follow for all the circuits you generate, even if doing so will break functionality for you. If StrictNodes is set to 0, Tor will still try to avoid nodes in the ExcludeNodes list, but it will err on the side of avoiding unexpected errors. Specifically, StrictNodes 0 tells Tor that it is okay to use an excluded node when it is necessary to perform relay reachability self-tests, connect to a hidden service, provide a hidden service to a client, fulfill a .exit request, upload directory information, or download directory information. (Default: 0)

Comment: [warn] You have asked to exclude certain relays from all positions in your circuits. Expect hidden services and other Tor features to be broken in unpredictable ways." hmm will my tor hidden service still be ok for the most part or..?

Comment: It will be just fine! Some lags are maximum penalties you can expect.

Comment: If I may suggest you a tip : try to add desired countries by curly codes to ExitNodes list. It will help you to utilize new nodes automatically